# Wordpress 3.0 Register/Login Menu Button

Tags: wordpress

I'm quite new to Wordpress and don't quite understand one simple problem that I have come across when working with the menu tool. I simply want to have the "register" and "login" buttons when the user is not logged in, and show a "profile" and "logout" buttons when they are, and with the theme I am using the login and register buttons seem to be shown regardless of the user status.

Any help would be much appreciated. I hope I've explained the problem enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**google for "wordpress member plugin"**

install best plugin you like

after installation you can use as widget on your side bar. Hance you get login and member info in sidebar or somewhere you want.

**Try**

[**Theme My Login**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin, this do what you are looking if not exactly

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BAW Login/Logout Menu](http://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-login-logout-menu/) WordPress plugin, its title says it all. I tried it and it worked flawlessly. This must be your case.